# Understanding how iter() works, does not call the object's __iter__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        def do():
            print("y")
            return iter([1,2,3])

        self.__iter__ = do

    def __iter__(self):
        print("x")
        return iter([4,5,6])

for x in A():
    print(x)

for x in A().__iter__():
    print(x)
```

The output is:

```
x
4
5
6
y
1
2
3
```

What I would expect as an output:

```
y
1
2
3
y
1
2
3
```

How does `iter()` (which is called by the for loop) work and why does it not call the object's `__iter__()` that has been overridden in the constructor but the classes' default `__iter__()`?

Edit:
Workaround:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        def do():
            print("y")
            return iter([1,2,3])

        self.it = do

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.it()

for x in A():
    print(x)

for x in A().__iter__():
    print(x)
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to answer it. So all I can do is work on a workaround for that then it seems